# Shrink wrap modifier

Tags: modifiers

I modeled this emoji using a shrink wrap modifier. I applied the modifier, but the emoji deformed a bit. I am trying to extrude the eyes inwards, but with the shrink wrap active, it does not work. That's why I tried applying the modifier.

[image]

Comment: i have no idea what you want to achieve...!? a screenshot or sketch how it should look like would help

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your topology is not dense enough in my opinion.

Your *Shrinkwrap* modifier is placed after the *Subdivision Surface*, so its effect will take a high density topology into account. But when you apply it, it only applies on the real and low-poly topology, and the *Subdivision Surface* doesn't count anymore, it only adds topology to the result of the *Shrinkwrap* applied to a low-poly.

So what you can do as a quick fix is apply the *Mirror* modifier then the *Subdivision Surface* with a level of 1 in order to easily add topology, then apply the *Shrinkwrap*, then give it a *Subdivision Surface* again in order to round it, and the result will be correct.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I applied the subdiv modifier. I got a cut at the center of the emoji

Comment: yes, you also have a Mirror modifier, apply it as well to make things simpler, or just move the vertices to the centers so that they stick

Comment: It did work. Thank you so much